# JS: Нужна регулярка компаратора для массива с уникальными ID элементов

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Есть массив следующего вида:

```
var myArray = [
'<div id="text13264" onclick="someFunction();"><button>2</button><span>Some text</span></div>',
'<div id="text56847" onclick="someFunction();"><button>1</button><span>Some text</span></div>',
'<div id="text45487" onclick="someFunction();"><button>3</button><span>Some text</span></div>'
];
```

Нужен компаратор для сортировки массива например (или другой):

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.match(???) - b.match(???);
});
```

чтобы отсортировать элементы массива по цифрам которые внутри тегов button (в порядке возрастания) и чтобы в результате получилось

```
<div id="text56847" onclick="someFunction();"><button>1</button><span>Some text</span></div>
<div id="text13264" onclick="someFunction();"><button>2</button><span>Some text</span></div>
<div id="text45487" onclick="someFunction();"><button>3</button><span>Some text</span></div>
```

Т.е. div с буттоном 1, потом div с буттоном 2, потом div с буттоном 3 и т.д. При этом нужно учесть что ID каждого div'a уникальный. Хотя `onclick="someFunction();"` для всех элементов одинаковая

Comment: И что не так с вопросом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[
  '<div id="text13264" onclick="someFunction();"><button>2</button><span>Some text</span></div>',
  '<div id="text56847" onclick="someFunction();"><button>1</button><span>Some text</span></div>',
  '<div id="text45487" onclick="someFunction();"><button>3</button><span>Some text</span></div>'
].sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.match(/\d+(?=<\/button>)/) - b.match(/\d+(?=<\/button>)/);
})
```

Comment: Маленькая дополнительная просьба: бывает что внутри кнопки не просто цифра а например цифра со знаком вопроса или с буквой например 2? или 26Б. Кнопки с такими символами ставит отдельно и сортирует неправильно. Как сделать чтобы сортировка работала и в таких случаях?

Comment: @stckvrw, попробуй `(?=\D?<\/button>)`.